# Enum in a class with strings

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to implement a class (C++) with an `enum` (with the permitted parameters). I got a working solution, but if I try to extend the functionality I get stuck.

Header `data_location.hpp`

```
class DataLocation
{
private:
public:
  enum Params { model, period };
  std::string getParamString(Params p);
};
```

Program `data_location.cpp`

```
string DataLocation::getParamString(Params p){
    static const char * ParamsStrings[] = {"MODEL", "PERIOD"};
    return ParamsStrings[p];
}
```

The array `ParamsStrings` should be generally available in the class, because I need a second method (with inverse function) returning the `enum` value given a string.

If I try to define the array in the header I get the error:

```
in-class initialization of static data member ‘const char* DataLocation::ParamsStrings []’ of incomplete type
```

Why is the type incomplete? The compiler is for sure able to counts the strings in the array, isn't it?

In case there is no way to get my code working, is there an other way? With 1) no XML; 2) no double definition of the strings; 3) not outside the class; 4) no in code programmed mapping.

Comment: You have to declare the array in the header, and define it in cpp.

Comment: Your question boils dow to "How do I define static class members?" to which there is enough existing code. Also, please provide complete (but minimal) example code if you want an error message explained.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You are right, see my comment to the answer from @blazs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class (header) use keyword `static` and initialize it outside (.cpp) without the `static` keyword:

```
class DataLocation {
    public:
        enum Params { model, period };
        string getParamString(Params p);
        static const char* ParamsStrings[];
    //  ^^^^^^
};

const char* DataLocation::ParamsStrings[] = {"MODEL", "BLLBLA"};
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you *have posted* is perfectly fine.

Here's the proof:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct DataLocation
{
    enum Params { model, period };
    std::string getParamString(Params p){
        static const char * ParamsStrings[] = {"MODEL", "PERIOD"};
        return ParamsStrings[p];
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = DataLocation();
    std::cout << a.getParamString(DataLocation::model) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message you are getting is not to do with definition of a static data member in an inline function - that's allowed.

There's something else you're not showing us.

Comment: I agree, but as I **wrongly** split the code in .hpp and .cpp (as in my question) I got the mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in my question (the second part) was that if I split the class in .hpp and .cpp the definition of the array (I mixed *char and string) has also to be split:

```
// data_location.hpp
class DataLocation {
  static const char * ParamsStrings[];
}
// data_location.cpp
const char * ParamsStrings[] = {"MODEL", "PERIOD"};
```

At the end I introduced a consistency check to be sure that the number of values in `enum` growths as the number of strings. Because the array in C++ is somehow limited I had to go for a `std::vector` (to get the size).

Code for `data_location.hpp`

```
#ifndef DATA_LOCATION_HPP_
#define DATA_LOCATION_HPP_

#include <string>
#include "utils/dictionary.hpp"

extern const char* ENV_DATA_ROOT;

struct EDataLocationInconsistency : std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
struct EDataLocationNotValidParam : std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class DataLocation
{
private:
  std::string mRootLocation;
  static const std::vector<std::string> msParamsStrings;
  static bool msConsistenceCheckDone;
public:
  DataLocation();
  std::string getRootLocation();
  std::string getLocation(Dictionary params);

  enum Params { model, period, LAST_PARAM};
  std::string Param2String(Params p);
  Params String2Param(std::string p);
};

#endif
```

Code for `data_location.cpp`

```
#include "data_location.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const char* ENV_DATA_ROOT = "DATA_ROOT";

bool DataLocation::msConsistenceCheckDone = false;
DataLocation::DataLocation() {
    mRootLocation = std::getenv(ENV_DATA_ROOT);
    if (not msConsistenceCheckDone) {
        msConsistenceCheckDone = true;
        if (LAST_PARAM+1 != msParamsStrings.size()) {
            throw(EDataLocationInconsistency("DataLocation: Check Params and msParamsStrings"));
        }
    }
}

string DataLocation::getRootLocation() {
    return mRootLocation;
}
string DataLocation::getLocation(Dictionary params) {

    // to do
    return "";
}
const vector<string> DataLocation::msParamsStrings = { "MODEL", "PERIOD", ""};
string DataLocation::Param2String(Params p) {
    if (p>=msParamsStrings.size()) {
        throw(EDataLocationNotValidParam("Parameter not found"));
    }
    return msParamsStrings[p];
}
DataLocation::Params DataLocation::String2Param(string p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < msParamsStrings.size(); i++) {
        if (p == msParamsStrings[i])
            return (Params)i;
    }
    throw(EDataLocationNotValidParam("Parameter not found"));
}
```

And also a unit test:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "data_location.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( data_location )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(data_location_1) {

    DataLocation dl;
    auto s = dl.getRootLocation();

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s, "/home/tc/data/forex" );

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(dl.Param2String(DataLocation::period),"PERIOD");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(dl.String2Param("PERIOD"),DataLocation::period);

    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(dl.String2Param("SOMETHING"), EDataLocationNotValidParam);
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(dl.Param2String((DataLocation::Params)100), EDataLocationNotValidParam);

}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ is very picky about what it will let you initialize inside of a class definition; there are some particularly non-intuitive rules surrounding `static` members. It all has to do with the ODR, and why all the rules are the way they are is not especially important.

To cut to the chase, making your array a `static constexpr const` member should shut the compiler up. With the C++11 standard, the restrictions were relaxed a bit, and one of the new stipulations was that `static constexpr` members can be initialized inline. This is perfect for your application, since the strings in your array are compile-time constants.

Answer (score -1):

The recent g++ compiler which support C++0x or later compiles thus code. Pure C compile compiles, too. Because strings in initialization like `{"MODEL", "PERIOD"};` implemented as `const char *` pointer to the char array.